# ESP32 GPIO commands

Tags: lua, nodemcu, esp32

I just flashed a ESP32 with new custom build for lua files, designed from:
https://nodemcu-build.com/ with dev-esp32<>BETA
And it seems to be working, I can connect with ESPlorer and the firmware is installed as viewed in the startup code.

Im trying to toggle the BUILTIN_LED, but I get error using the GPIO commands.
It worked out of the box with simple arduino code, did I mess something up or why is this not working?

Here is the log with error response from GPIO.mode command

```
Communication with MCU..Got answer! Communication with MCU established.
AutoDetect firmware...

Can't autodetect firmware, because proper answer not received (may be unknown firmware). 
Please, reset module or continue.
ts Jun  8 2016 00:22:57

rst:0x1 (POWERON_RESET),boot:0x12 (SPI_FAST_FLASH_BOOT)
configsip: 0, SPIWP:0xee
clk_drv:0x00,q_drv:0x00,d_drv:0x00,cs0_drv:0x00,hd_drv:0x00,wp_drv:0x00
mode:DIO, clock div:2
load:0x3fff0018,len:4
load:0x3fff001c,len:6716
load:0x40078000,len:11116
ho 0 tail 12 room 4
load:0x40080400,len:5940
entry 0x40080700
[0;32mI (69) boot: Chip Revision: 1[0m
[0;32mI (69) boot_comm: chip revision: 1, min. bootloader chip revision: 0[0m
[0;32mI (41) boot: ESP-IDF v3.3.1 2nd stage bootloader[0m
[0;32mI (41) boot: compile time 17:08:58[0m
[0;32mI (41) boot: Enabling RNG early entropy source...[0m
[0;32mI (46) boot: SPI Speed      : 40MHz[0m
[0;32mI (50) boot: SPI Mode       : DIO[0m
[0;32mI (54) boot: SPI Flash Size : 4MB[0m
[0;32mI (58) boot: Partition Table:[0m
[0;32mI (61) boot: ## Label            Usage          Type ST Offset   Length[0m
[0;32mI (69) boot:  0 nvs              WiFi data        01 02 00009000 00006000[0m
[0;32mI (76) boot:  1 phy_init         RF data          01 01 0000f000 00001000[0m
[0;32mI (84) boot:  2 factory          factory app      00 00 00010000 00180000[0m
[0;32mI (91) boot:  3 lfs              unknown          c2 01 00190000 00010000[0m
[0;32mI (99) boot:  4 nodemcuspiffs    unknown          c2 00 001a0000 00070000[0m
[0;32mI (106) boot: End of partition table[0m
[0;32mI (110) boot_comm: chip revision: 1, min. application chip revision: 0[0m
[0;32mI (118) esp_image: segment 0: paddr=0x00010020 vaddr=0x3f400020 size=0x1bdf4 (114164) map[0m
[0;32mI (165) esp_image: segment 1: paddr=0x0002be1c vaddr=0x3ffb0000 size=0x02fcc ( 12236) load[0m
[0;32mI (170) esp_image: segment 2: paddr=0x0002edf0 vaddr=0x40080000 size=0x00400 (  1024) load[0m
[0;32mI (172) esp_image: segment 3: paddr=0x0002f1f8 vaddr=0x40080400 size=0x00e18 (  3608) load[0m
[0;32mI (182) esp_image: segment 4: paddr=0x00030018 vaddr=0x400d0018 size=0x84a0c (543244) map[0m
[0;32mI (373) esp_image: segment 5: paddr=0x000b4a2c vaddr=0x40081218 size=0x0f074 ( 61556) load[0m
[0;32mI (398) esp_image: segment 6: paddr=0x000c3aa8 vaddr=0x400c0000 size=0x00064 (   100) load[0m
[0;32mI (408) boot: Loaded app from partition at offset 0x10000[0m
[0;32mI (408) boot: Disabling RNG early entropy source...[0m
[0;32mI (409) cpu_start: Pro cpu up.[0m
[0;32mI (413) cpu_start: Application information:[0m
[0;32mI (418) cpu_start: Project name:     NodeMCU[0m
[0;32mI (423) cpu_start: App version:      a8b46af-dirty[0m
[0;32mI (428) cpu_start: Compile time:     Apr 15 2020 17:09:01[0m
[0;32mI (434) cpu_start: ELF file SHA256:  af54a39e6c0fb11d...[0m
[0;32mI (440) cpu_start: ESP-IDF:          v3.3.1[0m
[0;32mI (445) cpu_start: Starting app cpu, entry point is 0x40081244[0m
[0;32mI (0) cpu_start: App cpu up.[0m
[0;32mI (456) heap_init: Initializing. RAM available for dynamic allocation:[0m
[0;32mI (462) heap_init: At 3FFAE6E0 len 00001920 (6 KiB): DRAM[0m
[0;32mI (469) heap_init: At 3FFB9260 len 00026DA0 (155 KiB): DRAM[0m
[0;32mI (475) heap_init: At 3FFE0440 len 00003AE0 (14 KiB): D/IRAM[0m
[0;32mI (481) heap_init: At 3FFE4350 len 0001BCB0 (111 KiB): D/IRAM[0m
[0;32mI (488) heap_init: At 4009028C len 0000FD74 (63 KiB): IRAM[0m
[0;32mI (494) cpu_start: Pro cpu start user code[0m
[0;32mI (176) cpu_start: Starting scheduler on PRO CPU.[0m
[0;32mI (0) cpu_start: Starting scheduler on APP CPU.[0m

Mounting flash filesystem...
No LFS image loaded
I (337) wifi: wifi driver task: 3ffc26a8, prio:23, stack:3584, core=0
[0;32mI (337) system_api: Base MAC address is not set, read default base MAC address from BLK0 of EFUSE[0m
[0;32mI (337) system_api: Base MAC address is not set, read default base MAC address from BLK0 of EFUSE[0m
I (367) wifi: wifi firmware version: ac331d7
I (367) wifi: config NVS flash: enabled
I (367) wifi: config nano formating: disabled
I (367) wifi: Init dynamic tx buffer num: 32
I (377) wifi: Init data frame dynamic rx buffer num: 32
I (377) wifi: Init management frame dynamic rx buffer num: 32
I (387) wifi: Init management short buffer num: 32
I (387) wifi: Init static rx buffer size: 1600
I (397) wifi: Init static rx buffer num: 10
I (397) wifi: Init dynamic rx buffer num: 32

NodeMCU ESP32 built on nodemcu-build.com provided by frightanic.com
    branch: dev-esp32
    commit: a8b46af905b759506e9fd5eabdadbd8beb83e7c2
    SSL: false
    modules: file,gpio,net,node,tmr,wifi
 build 2020-04-15-17-07-08 powered by Lua 5.1.4 on ESP-IDF v3.3.1 on SDK IDF
lua: cannot open init.lua
> 
gpio.write(2, LOW)
gpio.write(2, LOW)
stdin:1: bad argument #2 to 'write' (number expected, got nil)
stack traceback:
    [C]: in function 'write'
    stdin:1: in main chunk
>
```

Comment: iirc it's `gpio.LOW`, not just `LOW`, but the docs will tell you more about that — EDIT: Indeed, it's `gpio.LOW`, as you can read [here](https://nodemcu.readthedocs.io/en/master/modules/gpio/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per https://nodemcu.readthedocs.io/en/dev-esp32/modules/gpio/#gpiowrite (and the error message) the second parameter has to be an int; 1 or 0.

Your code

```
gpio.write(2, LOW)
```

appears to send `nil`. Your `LOW` is not initialized anywhere, is it? What should definitely work fine is this:

```
LOW = 0
gpio.write(2, LOW)
```

(or `gpio.write(2, 0)` of course)

Comment: Oh yea, this worked, I thought I could reuse more come from esp8266. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

> bad argument #2 to 'write' (number expected, got nil)

This tells what the problem is: The second argument to `write` is `nil`, i.e. `LOW` is nil. You can confirm that by typing `print(LOW)` and it should print `nil`

The reason is simple: `LOW` isn't defined anywhere;

<strike>as you can read in the [documentation](https://nodemcu.readthedocs.io/en/master/modules/gpio/), NodeMCU defines gpio.LOW and gpio.HIGH (which, behind the scenes, are just 0 and 1)</strike>

*As Marcel Stör pointed out, `gpio.LOW` and `gpio.HIGH` are only defined for the ESP8266 version of the firmware. For ESP32 you need to use plain numerical `0` and `1` instead (or define your own variables)*

Comment: "as you can read in the documentation, NodeMCU defines gpio.LOW and gpio.HIGH" - sorry, this is incorrect. Take note that we are talking about ESP32 here. We don't have these constants in the `dev-esp32` branch.

Comment: @MarcelStör I missed that detail, thanks for pointing it out :D